# Consultar 3 registros con valores en dos campos diferentes

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Quisiera saber como hacer la siguiente consulta:

Tengo una tabla en la cual se hacen 3 registros por captura que hace.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que hago es:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Recepcion 
WHERE Folio Relacion IN (8438, 8440, 8444..etc)
```

y dentro de esa consulta quiero que me mande los 3 registros que pertenecen al mismo `FolioRelacion`, y que en `ProductoPemex` uno solo de esos registros trae el valor de `34006`.

Es posible?

Comment: No entendi nada.. queres agregar la salida esperada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando hagas preguntas de Sql, crea el escenario mediante sentencias o un sqlFiddle para que otros replicarlo y facilitar la tarea de quien te ayuda.

El escenario:

```
Create table Recepcion 
(id int identity(1,1), 
 folio int, 
 tanque int, 
 productoPemex int, 
 FolioRelacion int, 
 satFacturaFolio int);
```

Insertamos los mismos datos que en la imagen a excepción del id que es `identity`.

```
insert into Recepcion (folio,tanque, productoPemex, FolioRelacion, satFacturaFolio)
values
(8439,3,0    ,8438,null),
(8438,3,34006,8438,null),
(8443,0,0    ,8438,null),
(8441,1,0    ,8440,null),
(8440,1,32011,8440,null),
(8442,0,0    ,8440,null),
(8445,3,0    ,8444,null),
(8444,3,34006,8444,null),
(8449,0,0    ,8444,null),
(8447,1,0    ,8446,null),
(8446,1,32011,8446,null),
(8448,0,0    ,8446,null),
(8454,0,0    ,8450,null),
(8451,3,0    ,8450,null),
(8450,3,34006,8450,null),
(8453,1,0    ,8452,null),
(8452,1,32011,8452,null),
(8455,0,0    ,8452,null),
(8457,2,0    ,8456,null),
(8456,2,32012,8456,null),
(8458,0,0    ,8456,null),
(8463,1,0    ,8462,null);
go
```

Una de las muchas soluciones que hay, pasa por utilizar el operador **Exists**

```
Select * from Recepcion
where FolioRelacion in (8438,8440,8444)
And
Exists (
Select * from Recepcion f
where f.FolioRelacion = Recepcion.FolioRelacion 
and f.productoPemex = 34006
);
```

[image: Result]

En el conjunto asociado al operador, lees los registros de `Recepcion` que tengan el criterio a buscar. `f.productoPemex = 34006`

Relacionas ese conjunto con el otro conjunto. Como son la misma tabla, por eso utilizamos el alias `f`.

En vez de relacionarlos por el `id`, los relacionas por `FolioRelación`.

[Exists ¿Cómo se implementa?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/17/exists-como-se-implementa/)

Comment: Eso es lo que necesitaba justamente men! eres un genio! muchas gracias.